# How to install and configure php in openwrt

Tags: php, openwrt

I have developed some pages in PHP and HTML. But the PHP pages were not working when I put these pages in OpenWrt www folder. I have installed php5 in OpenWrt. These pages were working fine with apache localhost in ubuntu. In OpenWrt, It has uHTTPd. **Do I need to install anything other than just php5 (other modules)** or **Do I need to configure something?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For PHP5 configuration on OpenWRT see: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/uhttpd

First, install PHP

```
opkg update
opkg install php5
opkg install php5-cgi
```

Install any other additional php5 extensions you may use. To see available packages:

```
opkg list php5*
```

Example:

```
opkg install php5-mod-sockets
```

Open your /etc/php.ini and uncomment any of the extensions you just installed. Continuing with the sockets example above the following:

```
;extension=sockets.so
```

becomes

```
extension=sockets.so
```

Now open /etc/config/uhttpd and add the following line:

```
list interpreter ".php=/usr/bin/php-cgi"
```

Don't forget to restart uhttpd:

```
/etc/init.d/uhttpd restart
```

One option in regards to your space (flash) limitations of installing PHP on your embedded device: if you have access to a USB port on your embedded device (like many do) you can set up your base openWRT configuration with extroot. Essentially you will boot to a USB drive thereby enabling all of the space of the USB drive to install packages and add files. See: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/extroot

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do need to install a server (such as Apache), and if you want data persistence, a database (such as MySQL)

I found a complete guide for exactly what you wish:
http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/lamp

Comment: good 1.. But I already have uHTTPd installed, So I may just need to configure php5 , am I right?

Comment: exactly, here's the link to do just that: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/uhttpd#using.php5

Comment: friend,this is working but am facing a problem,, the modules php5 and php5-cgi which are required, are taking more memory (> 1 mb) which is not that good for my embedded device.. any suggestions???

Comment: lower the available memory limit in the php.ini file, generally this is set at 5mb, going under 1mb would definetly impact the speed of your app if running CMSs like Drupal, try to keep things lightweight as possible in your scripts. Phalcon is famous for its low memory footprint: http://phalconphp.com/

Comment: I think the limit in php.ini file is for .php files,, If I am right , the memory issue I am facing is on the installing of the php5 modules ,, these modules are taking more space ( using command opkg install php5 php5-cgi,  from the link u provided ). Anything we can do?